# What does the "variable //= a value" syntax mean in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, integer-division, floor-division

I came across with the code syntax `d //= 2` where d is a variable. This is not a part of any loop, I don't quite get the expression. 
Can anybody enlighten me  please?

Comment: We should make this the canonical answer and close the less helpfully-worded [Two forward slashes in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444520/two-forward-slashes-in-python) as duplicate of this.

Comment: Another [2013 answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820104) which is easily found at [stackse](http://stackse.com) using **python //=** query.

Comment: google for "python operator" first

Comment: The docs have an index whose first page is entitled `Symbols`.  The `//=` entry on that page links to https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`//` is a floor division operator. The `=` beside it means to operate on the variable "in-place". It's similar to the `+=` and `*=` operators, if you've seen those before, except for this is with division.

Suppose I have a variable called `d`. I set it's value to `65`, like this.

```
>>> d = 65
```

Calling `d //= 2` will divide `d` by 2, and then assign that result to d. Since, `d // 2` is 32 (32.5, but with the decimal part taken off), `d` becomes 32:

```
>>> d //= 2
>>> d
32
```

It's the same as calling `d = d // 2`.

Comment: It's the same under this circumstance, but in general, it is not necessarily the same. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__floordiv__ vs. https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html#operator.__ifloordiv__.

Answer (score 7):

It divides `d` by 2, rounding down. Python can be run interactively, Try it.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
>>> a = 4
>>> a //= 2
>>> a
2
```

Comment: `a = 5` would have been a better example. (To contrast with `a /= 2`)

Answer (score 3):

Divides the variable with floor division by two and assigns the new amount to the variable.