# What is the difference between // and int with / in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

For example, for small numbers its basically the same

```
>>> 2*5//3
3
>>> int(2*5/3)
3
```

But for large numbers,

```
>>> int(3814986502092304*122/32)
14544636039226908
>>> 3814986502092304*122//32
14544636039226909
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535596/what-is-the-reason-for-having-in-python

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444520/two-forward-slashes-in-python

Comment: I understand that // does floor division (or integer division). My question is that if it's just flooring the result of division, then how is it different from taking the integer part of the rational division (/). The answers should be the same regardless of what I use.

Comment: Floating-point inaccuracies when representation large numbers